# Integer with a fixed number of digits in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column in MySQL database of the type`int`.

I want a number to be converted to a fixed digit number.

For example:

if a number is 69 then it should be converted to 000069

if a number is 230 then it should be converted to 000230

Answer (score 8):

The field would have to be `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` to hold padded values and then you'd use `LPAD` to convert it:

```
UPDATE table SET col = LPAD(col, 6, '0');
```

However, it would make more sense to me if this was done on the application side rather than database side (unless you need this value in `JOIN`).

Answer (score 6):

You can use ZEROFILL option for integer fields -

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  number INT(6) ZEROFILL DEFAULT NULL
);
```

But your MySQL client must support this option.

Try MySQL command line client -

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1);
SELECT * FROM table1;
+--------+
| number |
+--------+
| 000001 |
+--------+
```